# How realistic is the bear attack in Walker: Texas Ranger?

Tags: realism, walker-texas-ranger

In the episode "The Bachelor Party" there is a bear that attacks the two campers who are fishing, then goes after the rangers. How realistic is that in real life and what would make a bear do it?

Comment: Not having seen the particular show, I couldn’t say how realistic the shows portrayal of an attack was. If you are asking if an attack is probable, then yes. What makes bear attacks rare is the geographic separation between humans and bears. If that is removed by humans being in bear environments or bears being in human environments, bear attacks can happen. Bears are like any other territorial animal. They will attack if you are a possible threat, food, or just a nuisance. Moose, elk, wild pigs, geese, even deer will do the same. Even domestic animals will attack if their space is threatened.

Comment: one thing is depending upon the species bears can be cannibalistic and will attack each other to eat. i think the grizzly will do that. so this besides a female being protective of cubs and a male being territorial are reasons bears will attack. the polar bears that had apparently befriend sled dogs ate a couple of them the very first time there was not extra food set aside for the bears by the dogs' owner -- basically bears, like many wild animals, kill other species and even other bears with no moral reflection -- the previous dealings with the sled dogs apparently meant nothing.

Comment: I don't know if anyone is killed in the bear attacks in the episode, but here is a link to a list of fatal bear attacks in North America from the 1780s to the 2020s.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fatal_bear_attacks_in_North_America  It includes bears that attacked multiple people. The worst bear incident in Japanese hsitory also involved attacking multiple people.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sankebetsu_brown_bear_incident

Comment: And see the sloth bear of Mysore https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sloth_bear_of_Mysore

Comment: No matter what people think, wild animals are not people. Nor, are they pets. The only things that keep them from killing more people than they do is adequate food, water, territory and fear. Separation between animals and human settlement is a good thing. Even inner-city coyotes, bobcats, raccoons, possums, etc should be treated with extreme caution, apprehension, and respect.